# Interrupted Time Series Design with multiple groups

Tags: time-series, intervention-analysis

More of a conceptual question

The standard ITS design is pretty simple, regress:

`Y ~ Time + Treatment_Dummy + Time_Since_Treatment`

However, what if the scenario was that there's multiple employees with sales data over time and we are looking to ascertain the effect of a certain training T on sales?

Employees could take treatment T at different times and there could be 100 employees - each one could become an individual ITS analysis.

Is there a way to modify ITS such that it could account for this?

Comment: 0. Welcome to CV.SE. 1. Fun question (+1) we do not need a lot of modifications, just to allow for some additional explanatory variables to account for potential confounding/clustering, please see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight-forward solution is that we can define the time-point intervention was take as $t=0$ as in standard literature and the use employee *pre*-treatment information as fixed effects, including known time-varying confounders and seasonality, and finally allowing employee ID to be a random effect. i.e. we have something like:
`Y ~ Time + Treatment_Dummy + Time_Since_Treatment + Pretreatment_feature_1 + ... + Pretreatment_feature_n + (1|EmployeeID)`. Use of such "fixed effects" variables is not uncommon (e.g. see [*The effect of the late 2000s financial crisis on suicides in Spain: an interrupted time-series analysis*](https://academic.oup.com/eurpub/article/23/5/732/450167?login=false) by Bernal et al. (2013), similarly the use of the mixed effects approach can be seen in for example [*Segmented generalized mixed effect models to evaluate health outcomes*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00038-018-1091-9) by Saeed et al. (2018)). In any case, do check on residual autocorrelation though, we might need to define a more involved error structure to get accurate standard errors (or potentially bootstrap, in which case I suggest bootstrapping the *employees* rather than the rows of your dataset generally).